# JS Event CTRL + mouse over + hide text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to achieve this:

1. Hide text in a div
2. User will press Ctrl key, then put his mouse over a button - a javascript function has to be called, and the text in the div should be displayed
3. If the User releases the Ctrl key - the text should disappear (even if the mouse is on the button), similarly if the User moves the mouse out from the button - the text should disappear (even if the Ctrl key is pressed)

My work so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    loadHandler = function(){
        $("#selector").mouseover(function(e){
            if(e.ctrlKey) {
                //what do I have to write here so that holding CTRL will be recognized ?
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadHandler();">
<button type="button" onmouseover="document.getElementById('center').style.visibility = 'visible'">CTRL+mouseover</button>
<div id="center" onmouseout="this.style.visibility = 'hidden'">
        <h1>Text text text</h1>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vERXmM)

I have to admit that I just started to learn JS so please help me out :)

- how to make holding CTRL and mouse over be recognize at the same time ?

Answer (score 1):

Working sample,

MouseEvent.shiftKey, MouseEvent.ctrlKey

[MouseEvent.ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey)

[MouseEvent.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey)

```
   <img onmouseover="keypress_test(event)" onmouseout="keypress_test(event)">


    function keypress_test(event) {

             // false, no press, 
             // true, pressed

              console.log(event.ctrlKey)

              console.log(event.shiftKey)


             if (event.ctrlKey) {

                    // hide text
                }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly working version

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var keyPressed = false;
    var mouseovered = false;
    $("#center").mouseover(function(e){
      doStuff();
         mouseovered = true;
    });
    $("#center").mouseout(function(){
        doStuff();
        mouseovered = false; 
    });
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
         doStuff();
         if (e.ctrlKey) 
         {
             keyPressed = true;
         }
        else keyPressed = false;
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e){

         if (keyPressed) 
         {
             keyPressed = false;
         }
        doStuff();
    });

    function doStuff()
    {
        if(mouseovered && keyPressed) $("#center").css({"color": "#000"});
    else  $("#center").css({"color": "#fff"});
    }
});
```

I just haven't hidden the text by default. Or else It will be hard for yo find where it is currently. And don't forget to click on the `body` before checking. Else `keypress` wont be detected.

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0q5nszz/4/)**

Comment: Thank you @void , but I need this event to be triggered while I am holding down the CTRL and mouseover on a **button** . You can hide it as this is the main idea: when holding the CTRL + mouseover the **button** , text reveals. When releasing the CTRL or mouseout from the button -> text disappear.

Comment: Not quite. The text disapears without pressing the CTRL button

Comment: I dont think so. Just check it again.

Comment: I am using your given JSFiddle and the text dissapear even if the CTRL key is not pressed. This also happens on my localhost. I hope I am not too annoying. The idea of the entire code is that holding CTRL + mouseover on a button reveals a hidden text

Comment: I am gonna make a new thread on stackoverflow to avoid extended discussion and to add the two solutions. The second jsfiddle stil not working.

Comment: I hope that you already clicked the jsfiddle body before testing?